# Unpersist cached dataframe in one single job

Tags: apache-spark

In my spark job(spark v2.4.7), i chain many transformation like :

```
InputDf.transform(A)
.transform(B)
.transform(C)
...
.transform(Z)
  .write.format("xxx")
  .mode(saveMode)
  .save(Path)
```

In my transformation C, I have something like this :

```
  def C(): DataFrame => DataFrame = inputDf => {

    val cachedDf= inputDf.cache()

    val Df1= cachedDf.transform(...)

    val Df2 = ...

    return  cachedDf.join(Df2)
                         .unionByName(Df1)
  }
```

As you can see, i reuse my `inputDf` twice, thats why i cache it.

But how can I unpersist `cachedDf` after using it ?

Comment: If you just want to remove df from cache you can use unpersist function https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.unpersist.html

Comment: Where should i put it ?

Comment: I added more info in answer, hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

You can use unpersist: [Docu](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.unpersist.html) for Scala it is the same

You may use blocking = true if you want to force other computations to wait till this df is removed from cache

With default value (blocking = false) df will be marked to delete from cache but you cannot be sure when it will be done

In your case usage of this function may be tricky. Looks like you have a lot of transformations and single action at the end. Transformations in Spark are lazy and its true also for cache so if you mix in persist/unpersist in one transformations chain it may be ignored.

If after this write something else is going to happen you can unpersist your df after first action and your df will be removed from cache when during next action.

I did something similar to your case

import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

```
val data = Seq(("test", 3),("test", 3), ("test2", 5), ("test3", 7), ("test55", 86))
val data2 = Seq(("test", 3),("test", 3), ("test2", 5), ("test3", 6), ("test33", 76))

val df1 = data.toDF("Name", "Value")
val dfCached = df1.cache
val df2 = data2.toDF("Name", "Value")
val dfTransformed = dfCached.filter(col("Name") === "test3")

val result = dfCached.join(df2, Seq("Name", "Value")).unionByName(dfTransformed)
dfCached.unpersist(false)
result.show
```

When i mix-in persist/unpersist in one transformations chain it looks like cache is not used during execution:

[image]

With unpersist moved after action (show in my example) df was cached and cache was used during computation. Now i have blocks "InMemoryTableScan" which means that data are selected from cache

[image]